# Com fazer um count dentro do array

Tags: php

Bom tenho o seguinte array:

```
array (size=3)
0 => 
array (size=5)
  'valor' => string '10.00' (length=5)
  'forma' => string '1' (length=1)
  'parcelas' => string '' (length=0)
  'verifica_nome' => string '' (length=0)
  'cliente' => string '' (length=0)
1 => 
array (size=5)
  'valor' => string '1.51' (length=4)
  'forma' => string '1' (length=1)
  'parcelas' => string '' (length=0)
  'verifica_nome' => string '' (length=0)
  'cliente' => string '' (length=0)
2 => 
array (size=5)
  'valor' => string '10.00' (length=5)
  'forma' => string '1' (length=1)
  'parcelas' => string '' (length=0)
  'verifica_nome' => string '' (length=0)
  'cliente' => string '' (length=0)
```

Preciso recuperar a soma total do campo valor. Como posso fazer isso em php?

Answer (score 5):

Se estiver usando a versão 5.5 do php combine a função `array_column()` que extrair um chave de um array multidimensional. Com isso chame `array_sum()` que efetua a adição dos elementos:

```
$arr = array(array('id' => 1, 'valor' => 350), array('id' => 2, 'valor' => 200));
echo array_sum(array_column($arr, 'valor')); //550
```

Para versões anteriores a 5.5 é possível obter o mesmo resultado com `array_map()`.

```
$valores = array_map(function($item){ return $item['valor'];}, $arr);
echo array_sum($valores);
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o array_reduce, ele reduz um array a um único valor

```
$array = [
    ['valor'=>10],
    ['valor'=>30],
    ['valor'=>40]
    ];

$arrayTotal =  array_reduce($array,function($carry,$item){
    $carry += $item['valor'];
    return $carry;
},0);

echo $arrayTotal; //80
```

Comment: Nossa, eu outro dia fiz uns foreach loucos, com array_keys e mais um monte de bobagens. Sinal que preciso dar uma estudada nessas funções de array